# 64K method count exceed error , for close to 62.5K method reference count

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, dex

[image]

The method count for my app apk in the apk analyzer is shown as **62481**. It's close but still not over 64K. There's no other .dex file, only the highlighted  one. I still get the **"The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K."** error while running the app. If I make it a multidex application it executes without any issues.
Is there something I am missing? 
Thanks in advance.

PS. I also used an online tool at http://inloop.github.io/apk-method-count. 
It also shows the same count. 
[image]

Stacktrace:

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --output D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\dev\debug\folders\1000\1f\main D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_1db0d0b69914354c7a1f54768d6d2b5c56a14a07.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_836009343e593bdd8d97066c1d4d35a4bac1ee03.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\logging-interceptor-3.2.0_e343134b40348a9375191b04bcb9815ad536eeb2.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\support-annotations-25.3.1_0ba0705a7d535784c50abb2c1df9c6ecd3b76c98.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_2e91d022d43bd04e01ff1ad098ec0770289b4c62.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_2e8f50ec08e5c86040aa91ab1741d7343a67f4f8.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_56c577ef5726762c4031ca5dda95111b9dc7e458.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_8a11d8b5e54b85a6e1de144a7cb6b1a4e6fd4ab4.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_60ec19e545d0173331896d4142d37b46059c43a3.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_7f0598945bce91b289e292f0f55a3b3d72fbf351.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\jackson-core-asl-1.9.7_f4c11563ba078112f420d3670220ff4b972681f9.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_30f2ee70b7f228236ae4edfc7d2c64f9216386c9.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_59a52153273d00e2e703ed0658850f6a5d884966.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\okhttp-3.8.0_9dc1c3bb542549a12a11d8322d4a6481d2d02cf0.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_b2bda403ff0525ec0227a0f80e19afca69d12b67.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\butterknife-annotations-8.2.1_3a165264321d2f81fe77b7c2637671018e4cac57.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_cc143144ac466f41255b7f36bfbd3d0ea695a209.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_824200b22e8ea74a383eac9a277e3ac2464aa539.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_a4e001df1fa4644f23dcefc07868e903a5607863.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_e2ecd357ba3fb919c3a438530d0290e93647178a.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\retrofit-2.3.0_68728c00c537fecad305d89fa97c2421840a623a.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\eventbus-3.0.0_e0bff5f7960a2e7ecac4f69bde0f78a82ca5e63d.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7_5369f60c40e50a63d03a92ef2ae29385677ceb8f.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_c6b3c7487cd2e972f77ca0e03bb19710c73e53e0.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_91361bf27fc5b6e472e367aa00f031bba7c4c20a.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\pgsdk_645c5225a64fe7c0b1a59aec735ebc050640f22d.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_f85f3afb04ff29a87a12af3638aef9aae6220a24.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_a1fc8b96a2a8c9acf7c645a9259c58c41a1f26fd.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_a7d0bdd1c2bdc70470127f504b003285bc078fe9.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\rxjava-1.1.1_8e601112604030616d0454987beb13c6bd5559f7.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_cf60fb6a5a8e2e831c1ac5e904054d7cae4fb66b.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\bolts-android-1.2.1_747b105f3d05185ddbb7f3461fcfcfb14fd400ad.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_3df31fa2a2dfd25d1ef407482294b0a9e4681dd4.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_880f0190688e96d2158375d20eb2b6a3ad0a1c00.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_a9174f45b029718961bea6288c5ab72b69c8d83c.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\adapter-rxjava-2.0.1_e254eec75d7b47f606b6044afe4f5de923c90209.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\library-2.4.0_aa6ede67eeee82afb5059b7cc11f144669e8d317.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\glide-3.6.1_eaf678ca6bb624fad8c858722d2c87b6d59be41a.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_7daee3352899d51e4a9fe3f8b397499be0258db8.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_8f9dc6ff8f790bc8764ce044b5b1932958f23f34.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_30f0950a769a9270e254c7ca0c6a59f5f6401d22.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_4a2b2594a565922e474f16ffba114c7002d1a6cb.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_30fe7465623d9f918d58d6edc58452e68aefdace.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_df3ee71424be542d1c2312a5b88578621627461a.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\converter-gson-2.2.0_243824882f104fb7a674d1f7f050d17f53106431.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_411c4b35195250868998df3b091d787100369a10.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_d2afcb23c7f7377b02c40aa75147aaa062228f64.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\httpclient-android-4.3.5_f8796db42b8aa66927828d31c761f0fddedbb772.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\okhttp-urlconnection-3.2.0_d542fad0507536391190065b8f9437055ccb7ec4.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_aba481f309d2fb09d40e15dd99edc01c161c6ad6.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\android-auto-scroll-view-pager-1.1.2_c97341019a7b0d29b9d66da4f9922ddf63d2d79d.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_bed303341316ad80fca44d4ef59f78e331db2eea.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\okio-1.13.0_c8981a062393bcce02a0a96d7eada6216359b2c1.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_ecae2ffa55c32320769f0dbad6bfc31f8fe4b89b.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_1a190aa1f8a574c091a5817b5f14c3eb6fc7d54d.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_47e5bef139248db621fc15da425e6ef000f8d1bd.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_0f5cd2cb52b7d4f288ad9e8011572878dd28daf1.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\httpmime-4.3.6_c281370eb9c8ee9d741d91e11bb30c8e896b2a58.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\okhttp-2.3.0_4e123907da30c2cd9d1f9862f2daa77436911e75.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_79b6efa0386df702de375178db0cc4c91ee16251.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_7b485f1753fd8a21285f68f4a5e82b3c9e3b7ce5.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_fffbb83068c9bb8ccc07ebafbdf10bfbb39a5ed3.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_0c6da562aac3d9ee3da240276b4588219e13286d.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_4cb6cc03b1dfb6968d9ba10603ae4401cffc9ee4.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_7109e5c327c1f89c08882b5cd1861f4316a13978.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\gson-2.7_7ed1d08353e6bed2c04dde33c5774a7d806dc0e8.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\javax.annotation-api-1.2_8c1b8b35c9219706f347411da651634f419b0bc5.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_8b802d0ed2c87696bde342b3a35978ec09593815.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_ff73a2835210f90ea5eb74d9ee7d3d53acc7d0bd.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_8136d3746547bd087e4415cc0d16dea272792c80.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_9efdaefe6637a742ef19f1d0780d46930c401498.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_3993fa06956ed2627c1c4a6d5fb8e2698532576f.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_973b2919579e6677a87ed69b39531a634cc9caf5.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\okhttp-urlconnection-2.3.0_c4971a2461656fb7836c771c25274b1b14cbdd47.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\debug_41a4fb652b966a530aadf11ba3e268e403f48a5d.jar D:\Xyz\abc\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes_af64895670d5e2390fb265b2c8fec8bbd127ec31.jar}

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the APK Analyzer. If you can create a reproducible test case, consider filing an issue.

Comment: @kapsym please read the question carefully.Any help after that is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure but are you using instant run? Did you get this error without instant run?

Comment: @RushiMThakker No I have disabled instant run. I cleaned,rebuild and everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This was one of those oops issues.
The apk I was analyzing was a **release build** with **minifyEnabled true**. But while executing the app **debug build** was selected for which proguard was not enabled and hence the error.

Comment: I suggest you edit out the "raises another question" and put it in another question before you start getting "Not an answer" down/close votes (Not from me).  Reformat this as an actual "Answer" and accept it if you like.